# Launch Android app from within SMS/MMS message?

Tags: android, sms

Is it possible to to launch an application using a URL launched from within the Android messaging app (SMS or MMS)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the only URL recognized are:

- Web URLs.
- Email addresses.
- Phone numbers.
- Map addresses.

From [TextView](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-TW/reference/android/widget/TextView.html)'s [android:autoLink](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-TW/reference/android/R.attr.html#autoLink) XML attribute.

Comment: how to run the application, as the url set will try to open the in browser, I want to start the apk file by clicking certain link, which is send from another device...

Answer (score 46):

The previous answer was not correct.

You can add an intent filter for an activity that will "register" your app to handle hyperlinks within the SMS body.

For instance, if you add the following intent to your application.xml:

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"></action>
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"></category>
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"></category>
  <data 
    android:scheme="http" 
    android:host="test.com" 
    android:pathPrefix="/myapp">
  </data>
</intent-filter>
```

And you send an SMS message with the following in the body:

```
http://test.com/myapp/somedata
```

Your application will launch and the activity will be able to access the URL as part of the intent data.

Comment: This is a good answer. However when I use this method, it also shows an option of all the browsers that are present on the device. Is there a way to just open my app directly instead of showing the user with different options?

Comment: when I add this did not work. App icon from the app list is disappear and click on link in email not openning the app at all it is opening link in browser itself

Comment: @DineshSpartacus, I found wayout please refer my answer here

Comment: Thanks for update me...but i had already found solution and successfully edited in my projects..but thanks again

Comment: What's the solution for getting this to work on a phone that doesn't have the app installed yet? Say for example the app isn't published in the Google Play store yet, but I want to send the app link to my friend so he can try it.

Comment: I also get a app chooser prompt even if I invoke http://test.com without /myapp . How to redirect to my app ONLY if it is specific endpoint like /myapp ?

Comment: @AdamStyrc How did you do it eventually?

Comment: @ItayFeldman I fially decided to use branch.io - they make sure you will get redirected to Google Play store in case the app is not installed :)

Answer (score 6):

In addition answer given by @Adam,

There is multiple intent filter possible in case of android app, We have to use two. One for the app launcher and one for the launching app using the URL in sms

```
<activity android:name="com.SomeActivity" adroid:theme="@style/MyTheme"
android:label="@string/app_name"> 
    <!-- For app launcher -->
    <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
       <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
       <category android:name="com.YorAppPackage" />
    </intent-filter>
    <!-- To open app using link -->
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"></action>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"></category>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"></category>
        <data android:scheme="http"
              android:host="yourdomain.com"
              android:pathPrefix="/someurlparam">
        </data>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Now add a URL in your sms something like

```
http://yourdomain.com/someurlparam
```

This should launch the app on url click and will add a app icon in android as well.

Comment: Thanks. This also worked for me using a custom scheme, which avoids the problem mentioned above about a list of all the browsers opening.

Comment: @arlomedia How did you put a custom scheme? it wont let me click on anything that does not start with http/https..

Comment: I included `<data android:scheme="myappname" />` in the `intent-filter` block. But whether the link is clickable might depend on the SMS app that displays the message.

Comment: Yes, Everything that is part of another app you can not control.