# Run Application via link

Tags: android, hyperlink

I am working on an application where i have to create a link of my application and copy that link to text buffer and paste that link in my device in any text editor. Now when i tap on that link my application should open and show appropriate data. I don't know how to implement this i searched on internet I did not find any solution which can explain this feature implementation. give me the best way to implement this.

I have tried this but can not understand

[Launch your application when a link taped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16127822/launch-android-app-when-a-link-is-tapped-on-sms)

Comment: u mean u want the link in web when clicked lauch ur app?

Comment: yes may be. i can paste that link in sms or any text editor

Comment: not sure about text editor but I know how to do it for browser.

Comment: ok please share the complete implementation of that i am sure i will get my solution from that :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use other app to start it. You should register intent-filter with other action and category in your app. The most common action should be ACTION_VIEW combine with category BROWSABLE, then you can use a url in brower or sms to open you app. The intent-filter should be like:

```
<intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

        <data
            android:host="openmyapp"
            android:scheme="http" />
    </intent-filter>
```

Comment: where to type this in brower

Comment: please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958701/launch-custom-android-application-from-android-browser

Comment: Thanks let me try this