# SMS link to open app that is phone agnostic?

Tags: android, iphone, url, mobile, sms

So I'm thinking this may be impossible.  But on each phone platform there is a convention to send an SMS link, that when clicked, will launch an application on the device and do something based on the parameters sent in the link.

Ex:

iPhone: [Launch an app from a link in an SMS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3512664/1316346)

Android: [Launch Android app from within SMS/MMS message?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3086774/1316346)

However is there anyway to do this that is effectively cross platform?  For example I have an android phone with my app, and I send an invitation to a friend that has the same app but the iphone version (perhaps I don't know he has an iphone I just have a phone number).  Is there a way to send a sms link that figures out it's being opened on an iphone, and sends the link to open the iphone version of the app?  Perhaps there is a way to embed very simple logic into a hyperlink that changes based on what device it is?  Is there any way to pull off something like this?

I realize I could send multiple links and have the user click the one that is appropriate, but that seems a little sloppy (especially as more platforms become available, it will be cumbersome to cram all the links into 1 SMS message for every device).

Comment: +1 for you you forward thinker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a difficult situation with no easy answer unfortunately.
Option A) You send a link that points to your server.  This link identifies the device based on user agent and then forwards them to the proper sms: link for each platform.
Option B) If you know what type of device you are sending the link to beforehand, then you can determine the proper link on the server side before it is sent.

Comment: Are there any messages you can send to a phone that will identify it without simply asking the person receiving it?

Comment: Are you asking if you can send an SMS that will identify the device as iOS or Android? If so, no.

Comment: Was thinking maybe not sms, but if there was some kind of `ping` you can send to a phone and it responds with it's OS, but I doubt it.  Option A I guess is reasonable though.  Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @KevinDiTraglia Ya sorry, don't think there is a ping you can send unfortunately.  The link option is probably the best.  Sorry I couldn't be of more help!